# How we can fetch access token with the auth code using google docs api with PHP?

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client, google-docs-api

I am working on google docs api with PHP. I am facing issues while fetching the access token from the google api from the generated auth code.

I have coded like this-

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

function getClient()
{
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('Google Docs API PHP Quickstart');
    $client->setScopes([
                        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents",
                        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file",
                        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
                        Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_READONLY,
                        ]);
    $client->setAuthConfig('credentials.json');
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $client->setApprovalPrompt('force');
    // Load previously authorized credentials from a file.
    $credentialsPath = expandHomeDirectory('token.json');
    
    if (file_exists($credentialsPath)) {
        $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($credentialsPath), true);
    } else {

        $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
            if ( ! isset( $_GET['code'] ) ) {
                header( "Location: $authUrl", true, 302 );
                exit;
            }
            $authCode = $_GET['code'];
            echo "<pre>"; print_r($authCode);exit;  // I am able to get the auth code from here (my auth code is like "4/XXXXXXXXXXX...").
            $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode); // but from this I am unable to fetch the access token from the above auth code.
            // echo "<pre>"; print_r($accessToken);exit;

        // Store the credentials to disk.
        if (!file_exists(dirname($credentialsPath))) {
            mkdir(dirname($credentialsPath), 0700, true);
        }
        file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($accessToken));
        // printf("Credentials saved to %s\n", $credentialsPath);
    }

    $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

    // Refresh the token if it's expired.
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());       
        file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
    }
    
    return $client;
}

function expandHomeDirectory($path)
{
    $homeDirectory = getenv('HOME');
    if (empty($homeDirectory)) {
        $homeDirectory = getenv('HOMEDRIVE') . getenv('HOMEPATH');
    }
    return str_replace('~', realpath($homeDirectory), $path);
}
```

**Note:- I have already done like this below code-**

```
function getClient()
{
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('Google Docs API PHP Quickstart');
    $client->setScopes([
                        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents",
                        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file",
                        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
                        Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_READONLY,
                        ]);
    $client->setAuthConfig('credentials.json');
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $client->setApprovalPrompt('force');

    // Load previously authorized credentials from a file.
    $credentialsPath = expandHomeDirectory('token.json');
    
    if (file_exists($credentialsPath)) {
        $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($credentialsPath), true);
    } else {

        // Request authorization from the user.
        $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
        printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
        print 'Enter verification code: ';
        
        $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));
        // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
        $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
        // Store the credentials to disk.
        if (!file_exists(dirname($credentialsPath))) {
            mkdir(dirname($credentialsPath), 0700, true);
        }
        file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($accessToken));
        // printf("Credentials saved to %s\n", $credentialsPath);
    }

    $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

    // Refresh the token if it's expired.
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {

        $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
       
        file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
    }
    
    return $client;
}
```

From this above code I am able to get my access token from the auth code but the problem is I have to paste the auth url in my browser and from that I have to copy my auth code and paste it to the terminal and I don't want it like this.So i went through the fisrt code from which I am able to get the auth code without pasting the auth url in the browser. It just automatically opens me a new browser but from that the only problem is to fetch the access token.

And its throws me an error-

```
Array
(
    [error] => invalid_grant
    [error_description] => Bad Request
)
```

Can anybody tell me what I can do to achieve this? It would be great help if anyone could answer it what am I missing.

Comment: Is this a console app you are working on or a hosted web app?

Comment: @DaImTo,web app.

Answer (score 0):

invalid_grant can mean a lot of things but the most common cause these days is that your refresh token has expired.  You need to delete the 'token.json' file and then your app will request that the user authorize it again.  When they do you should get a new refresh token.

Refresh tokens for apps still in the testing have their permission revoked after 7 days when this happens all refresh tokens will also be revoked.  Solution is to set your app into prodcution.

Notes on your code:

Your app is going to be single user as there is only one 'token.json' file. this is not a directory. Your code IMO is designed for an console application not a web application.

The following section of your code is normally only used for console applications.  This is not something i would use for a web app.

```
printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
print 'Enter verification code: ';
```

## Web app example below

[Oauth2CallBack.php](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-APIs-PHP-Samples/blob/master/Samples/Drive%20API/v3/oauth2callback.php)

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/Oauth2Authentication.php';

// Start a session to persist credentials.
session_start();

// Handle authorization flow from the server.
if (! isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $client = buildClient();
    $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
} else {
    $client = buildClient();
    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']); // Exchange the authencation code for a refresh token and access token.
    // Add access token and refresh token to seession.
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    $_SESSION['refresh_token'] = $client->getRefreshToken();    
    //Redirect back to main script
    $redirect_uri = str_replace("oauth2callback.php",$_SESSION['mainScript'],$client->getRedirectUri());    
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
```

[Oauth2Authentcation.php](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-APIs-PHP-Samples/blob/master/Samples/Drive%20API/v3/Oauth2Authentication.php)

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
/**
 * Gets the Google client refreshing auth if needed.
 * Documentation: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2
 * Initializes a client object.
 * @return A google client object.
 */
function getGoogleClient() {
    $client = getOauth2Client();

    // Refresh the token if it's expired.
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
        file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
    }
return $client;
}

/**
 * Builds the Google client object.
 * Documentation: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2
 * Scopes will need to be changed depending upon the API's being accessed.
 * Example:  array(Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY, Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS)
 * List of Google Scopes: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes
 * @return A google client object.
 */
function buildClient(){
    
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAccessType("offline");        // offline access.  Will result in a refresh token
    $client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);   // incremental auth
    $client->setAuthConfig(__DIR__ . '/client_secrets.json');
    $client->addScope([YOUR SCOPES HERE]);
    $client->setRedirectUri(getRedirectUri());  
    return $client;
}

/**
 * Builds the redirect uri.
 * Documentation: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/auth/installed-app#choosingredirecturi
 * Hostname and current server path are needed to redirect to oauth2callback.php
 * @return A redirect uri.
 */
function getRedirectUri(){

    //Building Redirect URI
    $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];                    //returns the current URL
    if(strrpos($url, '?') > 0)
        $url = substr($url, 0, strrpos($url, '?') );  // Removing any parameters.
    $folder = substr($url, 0, strrpos($url, '/') );   // Removeing current file.
    return (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $folder. '/oauth2callback.php';
}


/**
 * Authenticating to Google using Oauth2
 * Documentation:  https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2
 * Returns a Google client with refresh token and access tokens set. 
 *  If not authencated then we will redirect to request authencation.
 * @return A google client object.
 */
function getOauth2Client() {
    try {
        
        $client = buildClient();
        
        // Set the refresh token on the client. 
        if (isset($_SESSION['refresh_token']) && $_SESSION['refresh_token']) {
            $client->refreshToken($_SESSION['refresh_token']);
        }
        
        // If the user has already authorized this app then get an access token
        // else redirect to ask the user to authorize access to Google Analytics.
        if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
            
            // Set the access token on the client.
            $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);                 
            
            // Refresh the access token if it's expired.
            if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {              
                $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
                $client->setAccessToken($client->getAccessToken()); 
                $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();              
            }           
            return $client; 
        } else {
            // We do not have access request access.
            header('Location: ' . filter_var( $client->getRedirectUri(), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```